# Prove that polynomial doesn't admit a particular solution

Tags: polynomials

Prove that the equation$$x^4+(a-2)x^3+(a^2-2a+4)x^2-x+1=0$$
does not admit $$x=-2$$ as a triple root.

Comment: Note: An equation has a solution, not have a root, much less a triple root.  A polynomial can have a triple root.

Comment: If $p(x)$ is the polynomial given, then that it has $x=-2$ as a triple root means that $p(-2)=0$, $p'(-2)=0$, $p''(-2)=0$ and $p'''(-2)\neq0$. These give you three equations that depend on $a$. Compute them and show that that system doesn't have any solution or all of its solutions would not satisfy $p'''(-2)\neq0$.

Comment: What happens when you divide by $(x+2)^3$?

Comment: Another approach that doesn't require getting your hands dirty is the following. If you change $x$ by $-x$ in the equation, you get the polynomial $x^4-(a-2)x^3+((a-1)^2+3)x^2+x+1$, for which the coefficients only have either two changes of sign (if $a-2>0$) or no change of sign. If $-2$ were a triple root of the original polynomial then $2$ would be a triple root of this new polynomial. But by [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes'_rule_of_signs) the number of positive roots of this can only be at most $2$ (the number of sign changes in the coefficients).

Comment: In particular, the argument above shows that no negative number can be a triple root.

Answer (score 1):

Check when is $f(2)$, $f'(2)$ and $f''(2)$ equal zero.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach.

Suppose it did. Let the other root be $r$. Use Vieta's formulae to compute $r$ and $a$.